# Functional reactive programming (FRP) in games. Some doubts and thoughts

Tags: c++, game-engine, frp

This days I'm doing some research on Component based entity systems. I had a first aproximation using a blackboard pattern at Entity level and components sharing this blackboard to do communication.

Doing this research I found an entity framework called Artemis, that follows a FRP structure for the entity managment. The idea seems pretty good and I'm thinking of integrating in my engine. But, I have some questions that need to be solved to fully understand this "odd" arquitecture:

1) In my first aproximation the way components shared data is pretty straight forward following the blackboard pattern. How should this be done following FRP? It seems, each system would be the ones holding all depencencies to components (Making components totally decoupled). I mean, if the collision system needs to know about physic component, movable system, etc... The collision system would import all this components and do all needed work with them. Is this right?

2) Would each system be a homogeneus or heterogeneus component container? I guess systems has to be homogeneus related to the component type they hold because the system need to know the component data to play with it during updates. This leads me to next question:

3) Doen't this arquitecture leads to have too many system/components?

4) How does an event system fit in this structure? I ussually have slot/signals in game objects for this but it seems with artemis structure there's no "Entity" concept.

Sorry for the long question and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post this question to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do I have to do anything special to do this? Or just paste the question there? Don't know if there's any way to port the question to gamedev.stackxchange.com

Comment: Could you expand upon what you mean by “homo-/heterogenous container” in 2)? And I'll follow the Q over to gamedev. Sounds like you're on the right general track

Comment: Well, what I wanted to mean by the "homo/heterogenous container" is if each system should be holding only a type of component. An example, imagine I have an AlienBrain component and a BugBrain component. Should I have 2 systems even though they are very related (They are 2 brains).

Comment: @Notbad: The easiest way to get a question moved is for yourself to flag it for moderator attention with a request for it to be moved. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just copied it anyway :).